# Deploy three projects on the same Weblogic domain. But the log4j write all the logs in one file

Tags: log4j, weblogic

Deploy three projects on the same Weblogic domain. But the log4j write all the logs in one file. But I want to write the logs into three files(each project has its own log file). How to config the log4j.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something like this in your log4j properties:

```
 log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
```

What you can do is replace that line with:

```
 log4j.appender.file.File=${mylog}
```

Then in each project, assuming you have the log4j.properties configured for each project, you should be able to do:

```
 System.setProperty("mylog", "specific_filepath_for_project");
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, log files for your two packages are:

```
com.abhi.packageOne;  ->  packageOneFile.log
com.abhi.packageTwo;  ->  packageTwoFile.log
```

Add rootLogger as file or console. You can keep any log level i.e. trace, info, errror etc as per your requirements

```
log4j.rootLogger=Debug, file
```

You have to create two new appenders for your two packages

```
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=/path/main.log
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE.File=/path/packageOneFile.log
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO.File=/path/packageTwoFile.log
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

You need to set additivity accordingly.

**What is addictivity ?**

In order to avoid redundancy in logs, we can use Log4j additivity. Just set the additivity property of an Log4j logger to false and then the log messages which are coming to that logger will not be propagated to it’s parent loggers. So, our new Log4j configuration file would be:

```
log4j.additivity.com.abhi.packageOne=false
log4j.additivity.com.abhi.packageTwo=false

log4j.logger.com.abhi.packageOne=DEBUG, PACKAGE_ONE
log4j.logger.com.abhi.packageTwo=DEBUG, PACKAGE_TWO

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG
```

Where MAIN_LOG is your regular log file. If you want to print logs from PACKAGE_ONE and PACKAGE_TWO in MAIN_LOG as well, then include below line.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG , PACKAGE_ONE , PACKAGE_TWO
```